# ASP.Net Identity CORS Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-identity

I am using identity framework in my webapi project. I have created just a default project with [individual user accounts] as visual studio generates.

Now problem is that when i try to access the Token URL like
http://localhost:58546/Token

but it returns the 
*(Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:58546/Token. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS) issue.*

I have enabled the cors in Apiconfig file like
config.EnableCors();

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can run a statically configured IIS site or do it in code as detailed here 
http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Comment: Thanks,  where i can add this                               Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");